# An Analogous Riemann Integral

Tags: integration, riemann-zeta

$$1=\sum_{n=2}^\infty (\zeta (n)-1)$$
is a fairly well known result

W|A [validates](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum%20from%20n%3D2%20to%20infinity%20of%20zeta%20%28n%29%20-1) this result

Is there a closed form to the analogous integral: $$\text{?}=\int_2^\infty \text{d}x \, (\zeta(x)-1)$$

I have managed to prove that the integral converges, but can get nowhere beyond a numeric approximation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $\zeta(x) - 1 = \sum_{n=2}^\infty n^{-x}$, your integral is 
$$ \sum_{n=2}^\infty \int_2^\infty n^{-x}\; dx = \sum_{n=2}^\infty \dfrac{1}{n^2 \ln n}$$

I don't think this has a closed form.

Comment: This is [OEIS A$168218$](http://oeis.org/A168218).